# Is there a simple way to use OpenSSL BIO objects in Java or are there any alternatives?

Tags: java, python, encryption, openssl, radius

Could anyone tell me is there any way to use `OpenSSL's` `BIO` objects from `Java`?

I'm working on a project, which is intended to provide support for handling of `PEAP` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Extensible_Authentication_Protocol) packets by TinyRadius.

I have tried to search any existing `PEAP` implementations in `Java`, but, it seems, there is no one.

Successfully, I have found an implementation, written in Python, which uses `pyOpenSSL` to decrypt and encrypt data within `PEAP` sessions. But the problem is that the code uses several `OpenSSL` features, which are not provided by `javax.net.ssl` like reading and writing into `BIO` objects of a `SSL` session or getting a master key and secure random, generated by the client from a session.

Here is an example of code, which I'm trying to port:

```
def get_keys(self):
    self.master_key = self.ssl_connection.master_key()
    self.server_sec_random = self.ssl_connection.server_random()
    self.client_sec_random = self.ssl_connection.client_random()
...
def write(self, data):
    self.ssl_connection.bio_write(data)
...
def read(self):
    return self.ssl_connection.bio_read(4096)
```

I have studied pyOpenSSL and found that all these calls are just wrappers for OpenSSL library functions through libffi (http://sourceware.org/libffi), but I have no idea of how implement the same functionality in Java.

As far as I understand the only way for me is use `JNI` (or `JNA`) to call `OpenSSL` functions. Also, I need to implement the code for managing lifetime of objects, created during `OpenSSL` access but I do not know how to do that, because I do not have any prior experience with native code from `Java`.

If anyone knows other ways to utilize `OpenSSL` from Java or maybe some ready-to-use implementations or ports of `OpenSSL`, please tell me - all answers are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After numerous searches for ways to utilize OpenSSL from Java I have ended up with JNA wrapper implementation, which, suprisingly, appeared to be pretty simple.

Fortunately, OpenSSL is designed in such way that in vast majority of use-cases we do not need to exactly know the type of the value, returned from the call to OpenSSL function (e.g. OpenSSL does not require to call any methods from structures or work with structure fields directly) so there is no need in huge and complex wrappings for OpenSSL's data types.

Most of OpenSSL's functions operate with pointers, which may be wrapped into an instance of `com.sun.jna.Pointer` class, which is equivalent to casting to `void*` in terms of C, and the callee will determine the correct type and de-reference the given pointer correctly.

Here is a small code example of how to load `ssleay32.dll`, initialize the library and create a context:

1) Define the interface to `ssleay32.dll` library (functions list may be obtained from OpenSSL GitHub repo or by studying the export section of the dll):

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public interface OpenSSLLib extends Library {
  public OpenSSLLib INSTANCE = (OpenSSLLib) Native.loadLibrary("ssleay32",
                               OpenSSLLib.class);
  // Non-re-enterable! Should be called once per a thread (process).
  public void SSL_library_init();
  public void SSL_load_error_strings();

  // Supported context methods.
  public Pointer TLSv1_method();

  ...

  // Context-related methods.
  public Pointer SSL_CTX_new(Pointer method);
  public void SSL_CTX_free(Pointer context);
  public int SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(Pointer context, String filePath, int type);
  public int SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(Pointer context, String filePath, int type);
  public int SSL_CTX_check_private_key(Pointer context);
  public int SSL_CTX_ctrl(Pointer context, int cmd, int larg, Pointer arg);
  public void SSL_CTX_set_verify(Pointer context, int mode, Pointer verifyCallback);
  public int SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(Pointer context, String cipherList);

  public Pointer SSL_new(Pointer context);
  public void SSL_free(Pointer ssl);

  ...
}
```

2) Initialize the library:

```
...
public static OpenSSLLib libSSL;
public static LibEayLib  libEay;
...

static {
    libSSL = OpenSSLLib.INSTANCE;
    libEay = LibEayLib.INSTANCE;
    libSSL.SSL_library_init();
    libEay.OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf(); // This function is called from                                              
                                              // libeay32.dll via another JNA interface.
    libSSL.SSL_load_error_strings();
}
```

...

3) Create and initialize `SSL_CTX` and `SSL` objects:

```
public class SSLEndpoint {
  public Pointer context; // SSL_CTX*
  public Pointer ssl;     // SSL*
  ...
}

...

SSLEndpoint endpoint = new SSLEndpoint();     

...

// Use one of supported SSL/TLS methods; here is the example for TLSv1 Method
endpoint.context = libSSL.SSL_CTX_new(libSSL.TLSv1_method());

if(endpoint.context.equals(Pointer.NULL)) {
  throw new SSLGeneralException("Failed to create SSL Context!");
}

int res = libSSL.SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(endpoint.context, OpenSSLLib.DEFAULT_CIPHER_LIST);
if(res != 1) {
  throw new SSLGeneralException("Failed to set the default cipher list!");
}

libSSL.SSL_CTX_set_verify(endpoint.context, OpenSSLLib.SSL_VERIFY_NONE, Pointer.NULL);

// pathToCert is a String object, which defines a path to a cerificate
// in PEM format. 
res = libSSL.SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(endpoint.context, pathToCert, certKeyTypeToX509Const(certType));
if(res != 1) {
  throw new SSLGeneralException("Failed to load the cert file " + pathToCert);
}

// pathToKey is a String object, which defines a path to a priv. key
// in PEM format.
res = libSSL.SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(endpoint.context, pathToKey, certKeyTypeToX509Const(keyType));
if(res != 1) {
  throw new SSLGeneralException("Failed to load the private key file " + pathToKey);
}

res = libSSL.SSL_CTX_check_private_key(endpoint.context);
if(res != 1) {
  throw new SSLGeneralException("Given key " + pathToKey + " seems to be not valid.");
}
```

`SSLGeneralException` is the custom exception, simply inherited from `RuntimeException`.

```
...
// Create and init SSL object with given SSL_CTX
endpoint.ssl = libSSL.SSL_new(endpoint.context);
...
```

Next steps may be creating of `BIO` objects and linking them to the SSL object.

Regarding to the original question, client/server secure randoms and the master key may be obtained via such methods:

```
public int SSL_get_client_random(Pointer ssl, byte[] out, int outLen);
public int SSL_get_server_random(Pointer ssl, byte[] out, int outLen);
public int SSL_SESSION_get_master_key(Pointer session, byte[] out, int outLen);
```

Please, note, that JNA will search dlls to load looking into `jna.library.path` parameter. So, if the dlls are located, for example in directory `D:\dlls`, you must specify such VM option:

`-Djna.library.path="D:/dll"`

Also, JNA requires 32-bit JRE for 32-bit dlls (probably, `libffi` constraint?). If you try to load a 32-bit dll using 64-bit JRE, you'll get an exception.